# Make program start at boot in Linux

Tags: linux, raspbian

I need to make a program called **gPodder** run at start on my *Raspberry Pi* running *Raspbian*.

The program is located at `/usr/share/applications/gpodder.desktop`

Can someone please give me step by step directions?

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head what desktop environment raspbian runs - could you include that in your question?

Comment: Note the difference between "on login" (which can run graphical apps) and "on boot" (which cannot).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit the file /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart and add the line:

@/usr/share/applications/gpodder.desktop

Source:
http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/auto-running-programs-gui

Answer (score 0):

There are four different ways of [Auto Starting a Program on Boot](http://pi.bek.no/autostartProgramOnBoot/)

1. `RC.Local` file method
2. `/etc/init.d/` Directory method
3. Cron method
4. Bash method

One of the methods suggested in [Raspberry Pi's Official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md) is below

> In order to have a command or program run when the Pi boots, you can
>   add commands to the /etc/rc.local file.

You should be able to do this:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
sudo /usr/share/applications/gpodder.desktop &
```